# How can I manage alignment with multiple rows and columns?

Tags: flutter, alignment, row, multiple-columns

I'm trying to make a card with some elements.
However it is hard to locate elements in right place with multiple rows and columns.
I tried with mainAxisAlignment, crossAxisAlignment, SizedBox, Expanded and so on.
Especially using Expanded make my widget disappear unlike my expectation.
How can I locate element to right place?

[What I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nw4e.png)
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjBf6.png)

```
child: Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Column(
        children:[
            Text('1'),
            Container(
                child: Row(
                    children:[
                        ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            child: Container(
                                width: 70,
                                height: 70,
                                color: Color(0xffD9D9D9),
                            ),
                        ),
                        Column(
                            children:[
                                Row(
                                    children:[
                                    Text('2'),
                                    Text('3'),
                                    Text('4'),
                                    ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                    children:[
                                    Text('5'),
                                    Text('6')
                                    ]
                                ),
                                Row(
                                    children:[
                                    Text('7'),
                                    Text('8'),
                                    Text('9'),
                                    Text('10'),
                                    ],
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
            ],

        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Do you know about `Expanded` widget?

Comment: I use it like Row(children:[Text('Text'),SizedBox(10,0),Text('Text')]) to make space in middle @Royalindo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this should be work as you wanted. i've tried to run it and yep it work

```dart
    Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text('1'),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 70,
                        height: 70,
                        color: const Color(0xffD9D9D9),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                PaddingText(text: "2"),
                                PaddingText(text: "3")
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                PaddingText(text: "4"),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                PaddingText(text: "5"),
                                PaddingText(text: "6")
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                PaddingText(text: "7"),
                                PaddingText(text: "8")
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                PaddingText(text: "9"),
                                PaddingText(text: "10")
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

and dont forget to add this to your project

```
class PaddingText extends StatelessWidget {
  PaddingText({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);
  String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! The alignment seems easy at first time but become complicated:)

Comment: hahahaha, for sure it a little bit complicated, but for all those design you can put it all device and that's surely fit at any device without overflow error, and upvote if you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

This must work

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children:[
          Text('1'),
          Container(
            child: Row(
              children:[
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 70,
                    height: 70,
                    color: Color(0xffD9D9D9),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children:[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children:[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text('2'),
                                Text('3'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text('4')
                            ],
                          )),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                          children:[
                            Text('5'),
                            Text('6')
                          ]
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children:[
                          Expanded(child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text('7'),
                              Text('8'),
                            ],
                          )),
                          Expanded(child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text('9'),
                              Text('10'),
                            ],
                          ))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],

      ),
    )
```